# Наследование нескольких классов другому классу

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Как правильно наследовать несколько классов, которые в свою очередь являются наследниками другого класса? [Картинка для наглядности.](http://clip2net.com/clip/m405748/05576-clip-13kb.png) На данный момент у меня написаны только 4 класса(Point, Line, Circle, Animation), но этого уже хватило для ошибок в компиляторе. Ошибки при компилировании:

```
In file included from main.cpp:6:0:
animation.cpp: In member function 'void ClassAnimation::set_shape_for_animation(char*)':
animation.cpp:49:34: error: 'ClassPoint' is an ambiguous base of 'ClassAnimation'
             coordX = ClassPoint::coordX;
                                  ^~~~~~
animation.cpp:50:34: error: 'ClassPoint' is an ambiguous base of 'ClassAnimation'
             coordY = ClassPoint::coordY;
                                  ^~~~~~
animation.cpp:51:39: error: 'ClassPoint' is an ambiguous base of 'ClassAnimation'
             width_shape = ClassPoint::width_size;
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
animation.cpp:52:40: error: 'ClassPoint' is an ambiguous base of 'ClassAnimation'
             height_shape = ClassPoint::height_size;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
animation.cpp:59:40: error: 'ClassPoint' is an ambiguous base of 'ClassAnimation'
             height_shape = ClassPoint::height_size;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
animation.cpp: In member function 'void ClassAnimation::shape_paint()':
animation.cpp:84:37: error: 'ClassPoint' is an ambiguous base of 'ClassAnimation'
             ClassPoint::point_paint();
                                     ^
animation.cpp: In member function 'void ClassAnimation::shape_clear()':
animation.cpp:101:37: error: 'ClassPoint' is an ambiguous base of 'ClassAnimation'
             ClassPoint::point_clear();
                                     ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:46:27: error: request for member 'set_point_height' is ambiguous
                 obj_point.set_point_height(set_parameter);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
point_class.cpp:29:10: note: candidates are: void ClassPoint::set_point_height(int)
     void set_point_height(int set_height)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
point_class.cpp:29:10: note:                 void ClassPoint::set_point_height(int)
main.cpp:50:27: error: request for member 'set_point_width' is ambiguous
                 obj_point.set_point_width(set_parameter);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
point_class.cpp:35:10: note: candidates are: void ClassPoint::set_point_width(int)
     void set_point_width(int set_width)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
point_class.cpp:35:10: note:                 void ClassPoint::set_point_width(int)
main.cpp:54:27: error: request for member 'set_point_coordX' is ambiguous
                 obj_point.set_point_coordX(set_parameter);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
point_class.cpp:41:10: note: candidates are: void ClassPoint::set_point_coordX(const float&)
     void set_point_coordX(const float &set_x)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
point_class.cpp:41:10: note:                 void ClassPoint::set_point_coordX(const float&)
main.cpp:58:27: error: request for member 'set_point_coordY' is ambiguous
                 obj_point.set_point_coordY(set_parameter);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
point_class.cpp:57:10: note: candidates are: void ClassPoint::set_point_coordY(const float&)
     void set_point_coordY(const float &set_y)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
point_class.cpp:57:10: note:                 void ClassPoint::set_point_coordY(const float&)
main.cpp:62:27: error: request for member 'set_point_color' is ambiguous
                 obj_point.set_point_color(set_parameter);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
point_class.cpp:73:10: note: candidates are: void ClassPoint::set_point_color(int)
     void set_point_color(int set_color)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
point_class.cpp:73:10: note:                 void ClassPoint::set_point_color(int)
main.cpp:64:27: error: request for member 'point_paint' is ambiguous
                 obj_point.point_paint();
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
point_class.cpp:79:10: note: candidates are: void ClassPoint::point_paint()
     void point_paint()
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
point_class.cpp:79:10: note:                 void ClassPoint::point_paint()
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Если наследовать классу ClassAnimation только один из классов Line или Circle, то программа работает корректно и компилятор не жалуется. Иначе, если передавать все два класса, то начинает жаловаться.

ClassPoint

```
class ClassPoint
{
protected:

    float *coordX = NULL;
    float *coordY = NULL;

    int height_size;
    int width_size;

    int color_point;

public:

    ClassPoint()
    {

    }

    ~ClassPoint()
    {
        delete coordX;
        delete coordY;
    }

    //Выбор высоты точки
    void set_point_height(int set_height)
    {
        height_size = set_height;
    }

    //Выбор ширины точки
    void set_point_width(int set_width)
    {
        width_size = set_width;
    }

    //Выбор координаты X точки
    void set_point_coordX(const float &set_x)
    {
        if (coordX == NULL)
        {
            coordX = new float;
        }
        else
        {
            delete coordX;
            coordX = new float;
        }

        *coordX = set_x;
    }

    //Выбор координаты Y точки
    void set_point_coordY(const float &set_y)
    {
        if (coordY == NULL)
        {
            coordY = new float;
        }
        else
        {
            delete coordY;
            coordY = new float;
        }

        *coordY = set_y;
    }

    //Выбор цвета точки
    void set_point_color(int set_color)
    {
        color_point = set_color;
    }

    //Нарисовать точку
    void point_paint()
    {
        setfillstyle(1, color_point);
        int x1 = *coordX - width_size/2;
        int y1 = *coordY - height_size/2;
        int x2 = *coordX + width_size/2;
        int y2 = *coordY + height_size/2;
        bar(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    //Стереть точку
    void point_clear()
    {
        setfillstyle(1, 15);
        int x1 = *coordX - width_size/2;
        int y1 = *coordY - height_size/2;
        int x2 = *coordX + width_size/2;
        int y2 = *coordY + height_size/2;
        bar(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
};
```

ClassLine

```
class ClassLine : public ClassPoint
{
protected:

    float *coordX = NULL;
    float *coordY = NULL;

    int length_line;

public:

    ClassLine()
    {

    }

    ~ClassLine()
    {
        delete coordX;
        delete coordY;
    }

    //Выбрать толщину прямой
    void set_line_width(int set_width)
    {
        ClassPoint::height_size = set_width;
        ClassPoint::width_size = set_width;
    }

    //Выбрать длину прямой
    void set_line_length(int set_length)
    {
        length_line = set_length;
    }

    //Выбрать координату центра прямой по X
    void set_line_coordX(int set_x)
    {
        if (coordX == NULL)
        {
            coordX = new float;
        }
        else
        {
            delete coordX;
            coordX = new float;
        }

        *coordX = set_x;
        ClassPoint::coordX = coordX;
    }

    //Выбрать координату центра прямой по Y
    void set_line_coordY(int set_y)
    {
        if (coordY == NULL)
        {
            coordY = new float;
        }
        else
        {
            delete coordY;
            coordY = new float;
        }

        *coordY = set_y;
        ClassPoint::coordY = coordY;
    }

    //Выбрать цвет прямой
    void set_line_color(int set_color)
    {
        ClassPoint::color_point = set_color;
    }

    //Нарисовать прямую
    void line_paint()
    {
        int end_paint = length_line/2;
        float position = 1;

        ClassPoint::coordX = coordX;
        int to_right_paint = 0;
        while (to_right_paint < end_paint)
        {
            *(ClassPoint::coordX) += position;
            ClassPoint::point_paint();
            to_right_paint++;
        }

        ClassPoint::coordX = coordX;
        int to_left_paint = 0;
        while (to_left_paint < end_paint)
        {
            *(ClassPoint::coordX) -= position;
            ClassPoint::point_paint();
            to_left_paint++;
        }
    }

    //Стереть прямую
    void line_clear()
    {
        int end_clear = length_line/2;
        float position = 1;

        ClassPoint::coordX = coordX;
        int to_right_clear = 0;
        while (to_right_clear < end_clear)
        {
            *(ClassPoint::coordX) += position;
            ClassPoint::point_clear();
            to_right_clear++;
        }

        ClassPoint::coordX = coordX;
        int to_left_clear = 0;
        while (to_left_clear < end_clear)
        {
            *(ClassPoint::coordX) -= position;
            ClassPoint::point_clear();
            to_left_clear++;
        }
    }
};
```

ClassCircle

```
class ClassCircle : public ClassPoint
{
protected:

    int radius_circle;
    float *coordX = NULL;
    float *coordY = NULL;

public:

    ClassCircle()
    {

    }

    ~ClassCircle()
    {
        delete coordX;
        delete coordY;
    }

    //Выбрать радиус окружности
    void set_circle_radius(int set)
    {
        radius_circle = set;
    }

    //Выбрать толщину контура окружности
    void set_circle_width_line(int set)
    {
        ClassPoint::height_size = set;
        ClassPoint::width_size = set;
    }

    //Выбрать координату центра по Х
    void set_circle_coordX(float set_x)
    {
        if (coordX == NULL)
        {
            coordX = new float;
        }
        else
        {
            delete coordX;
            coordX = new float;
        }

        *coordX = set_x;
        ClassPoint::coordX = coordX;
    }

    //Выбрать координату центра по Y
    void set_circle_coordY(float set_y)
    {
        if (coordY == NULL)
        {
            coordY = new float;
        }
        else
        {
            delete coordY;
            coordY = new float;
        }

        *coordY = set_y;
        ClassPoint::coordY = coordY;
    }

    //Выбрать цвет окружности
    void set_circle_color(int set)
    {
        ClassPoint::color_point = set;
    }

    //Нарисовать окружность
    void circle_paint()
    {
        float position = 0.1;
        float start_circle = *coordX - radius_circle;
        float end_circle = *coordX + radius_circle;

        float x = *(ClassPoint::coordX) - position;
        ClassPoint::coordX = &x;

        while (*(ClassPoint::coordX) < end_circle)
        {
            ClassPoint::point_paint();
            float a = -sqrt(pow(radius_circle, 2) - pow((*(ClassPoint::coordX) - *coordX), 2)) + *coordY;
            ClassPoint::coordY = &a;
            float b = *(ClassPoint::coordX) + position;
            ClassPoint::coordX = &b;
        }

        while (*(ClassPoint::coordX) > start_circle)
        {
            ClassPoint::point_paint();
            float a = sqrt(pow(radius_circle, 2) - pow((*(ClassPoint::coordX) - *coordX), 2)) + *coordY;
            ClassPoint::coordY = &a;
            float b = *(ClassPoint::coordX) - position;
            ClassPoint::coordX = &b;
        }
    }

    //Стереть окружность
    void circle_clear()
    {
        float x1 = *coordX - radius_circle - 1;
        float y1 = *coordY - radius_circle - 1;
        float x2 = *coordX + radius_circle + 1;
        float y2 = *coordY + radius_circle + 1;

        setfillstyle(1, 15);
        bar(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
};
```

ClassAnimation

```
class ClassAnimation : public ClassLine, public ClassCircle
{
protected:

    int border_left;
    int border_top;
    int border_right;
    int border_bottom;

    int min_coordX;
    int max_coordX;
    int min_coordY;
    int max_coordY;

    float *coordX = NULL;
    float *coordY = NULL;

    int type_direction;
    char type_shape[20];
    int width_shape;
    int height_shape;

public:

    ClassAnimation()
    {
        border_left = 25;
        border_top = 25;
        border_right = 25 + 250;
        border_bottom = 25 + 250;
    }

    ~ClassAnimation()
    {
        delete coordX;
        delete coordY;
    }

    //Выбор фигуры для анимации движения
    void set_shape_for_animation(char *shape_name)
    {
        strcpy(type_shape, shape_name);

        if (strcmp(type_shape, "point") == 0)
        {
            coordX = ClassPoint::coordX;
            coordY = ClassPoint::coordY;
            width_shape = ClassPoint::width_size;
            height_shape = ClassPoint::height_size;
        }
        else if (strcmp(shape_name, "line") == 0)
        {
            coordX = ClassLine::coordX;
            coordY = ClassLine::coordY;
            width_shape = ClassLine::length_line;
            height_shape = ClassPoint::height_size;
        }
        else if (strcmp(shape_name, "circle") == 0)
        {
            coordX = ClassCircle::coordX;
            coordY = ClassCircle::coordY;
            width_shape = ClassCircle::radius_circle * 2;
            height_shape = ClassCircle::radius_circle * 2;
        }
    }

    //Границы анимации точки
    void border_animation_point()
    {
        min_coordX = border_left + (width_shape/2);
        max_coordX = border_right - (width_shape/2);
        min_coordY = border_top + (height_shape/2);
        max_coordY = border_bottom - (height_shape/2);
    }

    //Рисование фигуры
    void shape_paint()
    {
        if (strcmp(type_shape, "point") == 0)
        {
            ClassPoint::point_paint();
        }
        else if (strcmp(type_shape, "line") == 0)
        {
            ClassLine::line_paint();
        }
        else if (strcmp(type_shape, "circle") == 0)
        {
            ClassCircle::circle_paint();
        }
    }

    //Стирание фигуры
    void shape_clear()
    {
        if (strcmp(type_shape, "point") == 0)
        {
            ClassPoint::point_clear();
        }
        else if (strcmp(type_shape, "line") == 0)
        {
            ClassLine::line_clear();
        }
        else if (strcmp(type_shape, "circle") == 0)
        {
            ClassCircle::circle_clear();
        }
    }

    //Выбор случайного направления движения
    void set_random_direction()
    {
        type_direction = rand()%4;
    }

    /*Смещение фигуры в зависимости от направления
    1   0
    2   3*/

    //Движение точки вверх вправо
    void direction_up_right()
    {
        if (*coordX >= max_coordX)
        {
            type_direction = 1;
            return;
        }
        else if (*coordY <= min_coordY)
        {
            type_direction = 3;
            return;
        }
        else if (type_direction == 0)
        {
            shape_clear();
            *coordX += 1;
            *coordY -= 1;
            shape_paint();
        }
    }

    //Движение точки вверх влево
    void direction_up_left()
    {
        if (*coordX <= min_coordX)
        {
            type_direction = 0;
            return;
        }
        else if (*coordY <= min_coordY)
        {
            type_direction = 2;
            return;
        }
        else if (type_direction == 1)
        {
            shape_clear();
            *coordX -= 1;
            *coordY -= 1;
            shape_paint();
        }
    }

    //Движение точки вниз вправо
    void direction_down_right()
    {
        if (*coordX >= max_coordX)
        {
            type_direction = 2;
            return;
        }
        else if (*coordY >= max_coordY)
        {
            type_direction = 0;
            return;
        }
        else if (type_direction == 3)
        {
            shape_clear();
            *coordX += 1;
            *coordY += 1;
            shape_paint();
        }
    }

    //Движение точки вниз влево
    void direction_down_left()
    {
        if (*coordX <= min_coordX)
        {
            type_direction = 3;
            return;
        }
        else if (*coordY >= max_coordY)
        {
            type_direction = 1;
            return;
        }
        else if (type_direction == 2)
        {
            shape_clear();
            *coordX -= 1;
            *coordY += 1;
            shape_paint();
        }
    }

    void start_animation_motion()
    {
        switch (type_direction)
        {
            case 0: direction_up_right(); break;
            case 1: direction_up_left(); break;
            case 2: direction_down_left(); break;
            case 3: direction_down_right(); break;
        }
    }
};
```

П.С. Работаю с устаревшей библиотекой graphics.h т.к. еще не изучал визуальное программирование да и с++ относительно недавно начал изучать. До этого изучал только структурное программирование на Си.

Comment: Попробуйте предоставить [mcve]. Цените не только своё время, но и время других участников.

Comment: В другом моем вопросе человек, помогающий мне разобраться в другой проблеме просил конкретный код программы, чтобы лучше понять, что у меня происходит. Теперь мне говорят, чтобы я минимизировал код, опираясь на простой пример. Вот только дело совсем не в размере кода. С пустыми классами A, B, C и D у меня все работает нормально. Так что не вижу никакого смысла показывать пример, который и так работает. Я вас не принуждаю тратить свое время на меня. Каждый сам найдет цену своему времени и решит для себя на что его тратить и как много.

Comment: Посмотрите виртуальное наследование, в данном случае я думаю это именно то, что вам надо.

Answer (score 1):

Множественное наследование - это вообще-то очень непростая и неприятная тема.
Вкратце - у вас получается несколько экземпляров базового класса, и компилятор просто не понимает, какой именно самый :) базовый класс имеется в виду. Решений два - в зависимости от того,Ю что вам надо. Либо обращаться к членам этого неоднозначного базового класса с указанием промежуточного класса, либо объявить его виртуальным базовым классом.

Вариант 1:

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A(int a):a(a){}
    void out() { cout << "A: "<< a << endl; }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(int a):A(a){}
};

class C: public A
{
public:
    C(int a):A(a){}
};

class D: public B, public C
{
public:
    D(int a):B(a),C(a){}
    void out() { B::out(); }
};
```

В `D::out()` мы вызываем `out()` того экземпляра `A`, который предок `B`.

Вариант 2:

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A(int a):a(a){}
    void out() { cout << "A: "<< a << endl; }
};

class B: virtual public A
{
public:
    B(int a):A(a){}
};

class C: virtual public A
{
public:
    C(int a):A(a){}
};

class D: public B, public C
{

public:
    D(int a):A(a),B(a),C(a){}
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    D d(5);
    d.out();
}
```

Теперь `A` только один, и можно обращаться без неоднозначностей...

Есть масса тонкостей - во втором варианте в конструкторе `D` надо вызывать конструктор `A`, например... Словом, читайте учебники.

Comment: Учебное заведение говорит, чтобы я использовал статические методы. Т.е. если я правильно понимаю: второй вариант мне не подойдет. Насчет первого варианта, не совсем понятна эта строчка `A(int a):a(a){}`, можете пояснить? В классах B, C и D, как я понял это наследование конструкторов, верно?

Comment: Ну почему же, вполне может подойти. Я как раз думаю, что исходя из логики задачи, вам больше подходит второй вариант. `A(inta):a(a){}` - это я просто такой конструктор добавил. Инициализирует член `a` значением параметра `a`, переданного конструктору.

Comment: С виртуальным наследованием заработало. Первый вариант не заработал да и, вроде как, не должен был, ведь он идентичен моему изначальному способу наследования, который не работал. Единственное, что не особо понятно - это: зачем наследовать и конструкторы конструкторам? Разве наследование классов не подразумевает наследование всего (переменных, методов, конструкторов, деструкторов)?

Comment: Конструктор у каждого класса свой, тут говорить о наследовании не приходится. Деструктор - тоже. Они не наследуются, просто вызывается конструктор базового класса (если вы не укажете явно, какой - будет вызван конструктор по умолчанию). То же и для деструктора. Кстати, раз у вас наследование - деструкторы делайте виртуальными! А вот методы и переменные - те да, наследуются. Но и тут есть свои тонкости (типа сокрытия имен и т.п.). Ну, а в "нерабочем" первом варианте вы, наверное, не обратили внимания в ` void out() { B::out(); }` на `B::`.

Comment: Да, не заметил этого. Т.е. в 1 варианте всегда нужно указывать нужное пространство для метода/переменной? А если мне нужно будет в классе D обратиться к методу/переменной класса А? Как правильно нужно будет написать это?

Comment: У вас, кстати в коде в классе D вызывается B::out(), а не D::out(). Это опечатка или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: В первом варианте в `D` есть, грубо говоря, экземпляр `B` и экземпляр `C`, и в каждом из них - **свой** `A`. Поэтому когда мы вызываем что-то из `A` - а `out()` есть только у него - нам надо указать, какой `out()` вызывается - того `A`, который в `B`, или который в `C`. Вот я и указываю, что это тот `out()`, который в `B`. Я *обращаюсь к `A`, указывая `B`*. Т.е. в классе `D` мы обращаемся к методу **`A`**, но так как их два - мы уточняем, что это метод того `A`, который находится в `B`. Так понятно?

Comment: Да, понятно. А если у меня в классе `А` есть переменная `var`, в классе `B`, который является наследником `A`, тоже есть переменная `var`. В классе `C`, который является наследником `A`, есть тоже переменная `var`. В классе `D`, который является наследником двух классов `B` и `C` и имеет ту же переменную `var`. Получается: если я захочу работать с переменной `var` класса `D`, то я могу просто писать `var`. Если я захочу работать с `var` класса `B`, то буду писать `B::var`. Для класса `C` - `C::var` соответственно. Вопрос: как обратиться к `var` класса `A` в классе `D`?

Comment: Какого именно класса A? :) Вот все 5 вариантов:     `D d(5);
    d.var = 1;
    d.B::var = 2;
    d.C::var = 3;
    d.B::A::var = 4;
    d.C::A::var = 5;` Это по очереди `var` из: `D`,`B`,`С`, `А` в `B` и `A` в `C`... Ну, или внутри класса D соответственно `var = 1;
    B::var = 2;
    C::var = 3;
    B::A::var = 4;
    C::A::var = 5;`

Comment: [Прикрепил код](https://github.com/kennydzzze/test/blob/master/main.cpp). В классе D в комментариях указаны ошибки для каждого вызова. Меня интересует правильная работа двух вызовов `var = B::A::var` и `var = C::A::var`, которые, судя по вашим словам, должны работать, но не работают. Возможно, я снова что-то упустил, но не могу понять что именно. Мне нужно в классе `D` обратиться к переменной `var` класса `A`.

Comment: Мда, VC++ 2015 нормально работает... Надо специалистов спрашивать...

Comment: См. дискуссию тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581103/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-vc?s=1|0.0000

Comment: Да, проверил в VS, все работает. До этого я использовал g++ в sublime text. Может стандарт какой-то нужный не указан для таких операций...

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор выдает сообщения об ошибках, потому что ваши классы, как правило, имеют несколько базовых классов `ClassPoint` , то есть в калссе создается несколько подобъектов типа `ClassPoint`, и вызов метода или обращение к члену данных этого класса является неоднозначным.

Вам следует использовать виртуальное наследование.

Согласно той схеме иерархии классов, на которую вы ссылаетесь в своем вопросе. то объявления классов должны выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassPoint
{
};

class ClassEllipse : virtual public ClassPoint
{
};

class ClassCircle : virtual public ClassPoint
{
};

class ClassLine : virtual public ClassPoint
{
};

class ClassRectangle : virtual public ClassLine
{
};

class ClassRhomb : virtual public ClassLine
{
};

class Animation : 
    public ClassEllipse, public ClassCircle, 
    public ClassLine, public ClassRectangle, public ClassRhomb
{
};

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Однако я не вижу большого смысла в том, что все классы наследуют класс `ClassPoint`. Во-первых, сам класс `ClassPoint` выглядит неестественно. Что означает ширина и высота точки?

```
class ClassPoint
{
protected:

    float *coordX = NULL;
    float *coordY = NULL;

    int height_size;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    int width_size;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //...
```

Почему координаты по осям указаны как указатели, а не просто объекты типа `float` ?

Почему, например, класс `ClassLine`

```
class ClassLine : public ClassPoint
{
protected:

    float *coordX = NULL;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    float *coordY = NULL;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //...
```

определяет какие-то непонятные свои координаты, а не использует класс `ClassPoint`? Какой смысл в наследовании от класса `ClassPoint`?

На мой взгляд ни один класс не должен наследовать класс `ClassPoint`, а должны использовать этот класс для определения точек фигуры, как, например, координаты центра окружности, или точки прямоугольника.

Например, определение класса `ClassCircle` могло бы выглядеть следующим образом

```
class ClassCircle : public ClassPoint
{
protected:
    int radius_circle;
    ClassPoint center;
    //...
```

При этом каждая фигура должна "уметь" себя рисовать. А класс `ClassAnimation` не должен от этих фигур наследоваться.

Кстати сказать, это хороший предлог почитать про шаблоны проектирования. Думаю, что такая модель уже описана в одном из шаблонов.:)

Comment: Ширина и высота точки определяют размер точки, да, у меня это не совсем точка, а прямоугольник или квадрат. ClassLine имеет координаты, которые указывают на центровые координаты линии. А то что все координаты - указатели, то это нужно мне для класса ClassAnimation, чтобы с помощью одного указателя изменять адреса других указателей-координат.

Comment: @ShitCode Я думаю, что вы используете неверную схему наследования. Если ClassPoint - это некоторый прямоугольник, то вы могли бы его назвать, например, как рамка - Frame, и определить в нем те методы, которым будут посланы сообщения из класса ClassAnimation.

Comment: Класс Point это класс точки, которой я рисую фигуры. В связи с тем, что мои возможности ограничены библиотекой graphics.h я выбрал функцию рисования bar, которая работает гораздо быстрее функции circle. Не нужно воспринимать класс Point так прямо. Размеры этой точки(квадрата) задаются пользователем с клавиатуры, если выбрать небольшой размер(3 пикселя например), то окружность и линия будут выглядеть вполне себе прилично.

Comment: @ShitCode Все равно непонятно, почему другие классы наследует этот класс.

Comment: Еще раз по поводу координат в каждом классе расскажу. Если в классе есть coordX и coordY, то это значит, что это координаты центра той фигуры, в каком классе они описаны. Т.е. если в классе circle есть эти две координаты, то это значит, что это координаты центра окружности, которые нужны будут в классе Animation. Получается так, что в зависимости от фигуры, которую я хочу начать анимировать, я буду ЕЩЕ одним (уже более общим) координатам в классе Animation присваивать соответствующие адреса той или иной фигуры. Это я сделал для того, чтобы не писать алгоритм движения для каждой фигуры.

Comment: Потому что, чтобы мне нарисовать прямую или окружность, я должен обратиться к точке. Методы рисования фигур в классах Line и Circle используют метод рисования точки.

Comment: Решил написать программу с помощью виртуального наследования. Используя ваш пример заработали только point, line и circle. Когда я начал писать rectangle, используя методы класса line и написав наследование следующим образом в классе rectangle - `virtual public ClassLine`, а в классе animation - `public Rectangle`, то компилятор снова стал жаловаться на ту же ошибку. [Это только часть всех ошибок.](http://clip2net.com/clip/m405748/3e22e-clip-12kb.png)

Comment: [Последний вид кода, если нужно.](https://github.com/kennydzzze/test/) Rectangle не дописан еще, на метод рисования прямоугольника не стоит заострять внимание.

Comment: Все, я нашел ошибку. Не надо было классу `Animation` наследовать класс `Line`, если `Line` наследует `Rectangle`. В общем, нужно было наследовать только `Rectangle`.

Comment: @ShitCode Вам виднее. Есть разные подходы к проектировании подобных классов.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное именно из-за такой фигни в нормальных яп и отменили множественное наследование. Это плохая структура. Либо наследуй от класса "ClassPoint" класс  "ClassAnimation", а от него остальные. либо вообще не наследуй "ClassAnimation", а сделай как отдельный инструмент(причем анимация к примитивам??).

Почитай тут есть решение таких косяков
http://www.quizful.net/post/Inheritance-in-C++

А проблема в том что компилятор не знает какую реализацию базового класса включить.