# Множественное наследование и VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, множественное-наследование

В ходе дискуссии пришли к такой программе:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
    int var;
public:
    A(int x)
    {
        var = x;    // Это обращение к A::var
    }
};

class B: public A
{
protected:
    int var;
public:
    B():A(2)
    {
        var = 4;  // Обращение к B::var
    }
};

class C: public A
{
protected:
    int var;
public:
    C():A(3)
    {
        var = 6;    // Обращение к C::var
    }
};


class D: public B, public C
{
protected:
    int var;
public:

    void method()
    {
        var = B::A::var;       // Должен выдать 2
        cout << var << endl;

        var = C::A::var;       // Должен выдать 3
        cout << var << endl;

        var = B::var;          // Должен выдать 4
        cout << var << endl;

        var = C::var;          // Должен выдать 6
        cout << var << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D obj;
    obj.method();
}
```

Программа отлично компилируется и выводит то, что и ожидалось - в Visual C++ 2015. Попытка скомпилировать с помощью GCC на ideone.com дает массу ошибок:

```
prog.cpp: In member function 'void D::method()':
prog.cpp:46:21: error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'
         var = B::A::var;       // Должен выдать 2
                     ^
prog.cpp:49:21: error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'
         var = C::A::var;       // Должен выдать 3
                     ^
```

Вопрос к знатокам стандарта - кто тут неправ, а кто прав? Если неправ VC++, то в чем, почему и как надо поступать *правильно*?

**Update 22.10.2016**

Пожалуй, наиболее переносимо будет не полагаться на name lookup, а воспользоваться преобразованиями в духе

```
var = static_cast<A*>(static_cast<B*>(this))->var;
var = ((A*)(C*)this)->var;
```

Но при этом нужно делать `var` в `A` `public`'ом. (Опять же не понимаю, почему и где на это ссылка в стандарте...) Полный код тут - http://ideone.com/wt9yrz

Comment: В вашем примере отсутствует класс D, поэтому сообщение об ошибке не релевантно.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Да, простите! Как-то я ухитрился его потерять... Еще и не совсем те сообщения об ошибках дал. Надеюсь, теперь вопрос выглядит прилично :)

Comment: clang, кстати, [выводит](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QCAgB6r5cuk3tBHb) цепочку неоднозначных путей наследования в ошибке.

Comment: @alexolut Но ведь, казалось бы, ему ясно указывается, откуда брать имя?

Comment: а может сразу наследоваться через pure а не через public?

Comment: кстати g++ пишет ровно тоже самое.

Comment: Я нашел такую ссылку, думаю там есть ответ, но у меня нет времени его найти) http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mi

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb мне кажется, искать надо в следующем [параграфе](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup).

Comment: ага.
нельзя обращаться через класс, т.е. запись C::A::var не допустима, но можно вызвать функцию из С, которая доступится до правильного А

Comment: Любопытно, что VS съедает `A::var` без [вопросов](http://rextester.com/AXN21979). Хотя тут явно должна быть неоднозначность.

Comment: @vasily-vm где сказано, что запись `C::A::var` недопустима?

Comment: тут http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:qualified-id

Comment: Вот такой вариант, как выяснилось, работает (впрочем, оно и понятно...): `var = static_cast<A*>(static_cast<C*>(this))->var;` Правда, `var` в `A` надо делать `public`. Кстати, тоже не пойму что-то, почему ему `protected` не хватает?

Comment: @alexolut Да, тут VC++ явно погорячился... А вот `static_cast<A*>(this)->var;` он не пропускает.

Comment: @vasily-vm не могли бы Вы быть более конкретны?

Comment: @vasily-vm Откровенно говоря, не смог там такого прочесть... Не могли бы вы пояснить подробнее? И - гляньте на обновленный вопрос, что там подскажете?...

Comment: @alexolut Гляньте на обновленный вопрос, может, поясните убогому :), почему `protected` не работает?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно указал @Ant, студия здесь неправа и всё дело в том, что подобные обращения `A::B::C::D::E::F` являются именно обращениями к *вложенным*(nested) сущностям, т.е. `B` должен быть сущностью вложенной в `A`, `С` в `B` и так далее. Это можно видеть в не нормативной ссылке в стандарте:

> **[basic.lookup.qual]p2** [Note: Multiply qualified names, such as
>   N1::N2::N3::n, can be used to refer to members of nested classes (9.7)
>   or members of nested namespaces. — end note]

Т.е. мы можем ссылаться на несколько уровней, но эти ссылки должны идти по нисходящей, никаких восходящих, либо же смешанных уровней.

Тогда почему это вообще компилируется?(оно компилируется пока не встречает неоднозначность, уберём неоднозначность и всё заработает). Потому что есть следующее правило по поиску скрытых имён:

> **[class.qual]p3** A class member name hidden by a name in a nested
>   declarative region or by the name of a derived class member can still
>   be found if qualified by the name of its class followed by the ::
>   operator.

И тут получается, что `C::A::var` должно интерпретироваться как `A::var`, где `C::` является избыточным квалификатором, который не несёт никакой смысловой нагрузки. Никакой другой интерпретации тут быть не может, т.к. `C` не содержит *внутреннего* класса с именем `A`.

Суть ошибки, кстати, хорошо видна с Resharper: он сразу показывается, что квалификаторы `C::` и `B::` избыточны.

---

Что касается второй части вопроса(обновления): не работает это по простой причине: классы наследники имеют доступ к данным предка только через `this`, у них нет доступа к данным *произвольных* объектов этих классов. Это описано в **[class.access.base]p5**, а конкретно, случай из вопроса, в **(5.3)**:

> m as a member of N is protected, and R occurs in a member or friend
>   of class N, or in a member or friend of a class P derived from N,
>   **where m as a member of P is public, private, or protected**,

Comment: *"C не содержит внутреннего класса с именем A"*. На самом деле это не совсем так. Класса не содержит, но имя типа содержит. Каждый класс содержит внутри себя в качестве публичного члена свое собственное имя - это т.наз. *injected-class-name* - котрое наследуется производными классами. Именно благодаря этому, например, мы можем в данном примере в `main` декларировать `B::A a` или `class B::B::B::A::A::A::A a`.

Comment: С первой частью, кажется, понял, но вот вторая - не очень: а как мы обращаемся, если не через `this`? `var = static_cast<A*>(static_cast<B*>(this))->var;`?

Comment: @AnT, ну, это ведь не расширение видимости, т.е. он не является nested типом, так?

Comment: @Harry, Вы `this` привели к какому-то типу и он перестал после этого быть `this` — это просто какой-то указатель. Этот случай рассмотрен в той части стандарта, что я привёл. Как иначе мог бы компилятор отличить просто `A*` от `A*` полученного из `this`?

Comment: @ixSci Тогда как правильно обратиться к этому protected члену того A, который предок B?

Comment: @Harry, без дополнительного кода — никак. Нужно делать `B` другом `A`, либо в `B` делать `using A::var`.

Comment: @ixSci Мда, почесать ухо пяткой :) Ну, вроде теперь уже получил определенную ясность в голове...

Comment: @Harry, просто Ваш вопрос вырос изначально из сомнительного кода. Всё-таки ромбовидное наследование с данными, если необходимо, то оно должно быть виртуальным. В качестве академического интереса — сойдёт, но так код всё равно писать не стоит.

Comment: @Harry, можете почитать пару ответов на тему доступа у Липперта, там про C#, но суть та же: [раз](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904782/whats-the-real-reason-for-preventing-protected-member-access-through-a-base-sib) и [два](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/11/09/why-cant-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class/)

Comment: @ixSci Ну, это понятно :) Само собой, не для практических нужд, да и вообще - явно нарушено тут несколько принципов проектирования. Но почему-то обычно самые интересные вопросы к практике не имеют особого отношения :)

Answer (score 8):

Прав GCC. Имена вида `B::A::var` и `C::A::var` - это не более чем квалифицированные имена, включающие в качестве *nested-name-specifier* имена класс-типов `B::A` и `C::A`. Это не более чем однозначный способ сослаться на сам базовый тип, в котором будет искаться имя `var`. И имя `B::A`, и имя `C::A` ссылаются на один и тот же базовый тип `A`. Он же - `::A`. По этой причине оба имени эквивалентны друг другу и эквивалентны также `::A::var`. То есть для расширения эксперимента вы можете добавить в функцию `method()` еще и доступ через `::A::var` и получить абсолютно ту же саму ошибку.

Для того, чтобы подчеркнуть эту эквивалентность, можно переписать код внутри `method()` так

```
typedef B::A BA;
typedef C::A CA;
typedef ::A AA;

static_assert(std::is_same<BA, AA>::value);
static_assert(std::is_same<CA, AA>::value);

BA::var; // неоднозначность
CA::var; // неоднозначность
AA::var; // неоднозначность
```

Очевидно, что все три имени - `BA`, `CA` и `AA` - обозначают один и тот же тип. Поэтому нет никаких причин ожидать, что доступы через `BA::var`, `CA::var` или `AA::var` будут вести себя по-разному.

Обратите также внимание, что если вы устраните множественное наследование (и вызванную им неоднозначность), то доступ через `::A::var` будет прекрасно работать внутри `method()`, несмотря на то, что если рассматривать его как способ задания "пути доступа", то он выглядит "неправильно".

Другими словами, *nested-name-specifier* в *qualified-id* не рассматривается языком как указание "пути прохождения" через вложенные scopes в процессе name lookup. Язык в данном случае рассматривает *nested-name-specifier* лишь как способ задания scope, в котором следует искать имя, после чего это имя интерпретируется "на общих основаниях" в том контексте, в котором оно использовано.

P.S. Интересно заметить, что в исходном примере MSVC допускает такое обращение

```
void method()
{
  var = ::A::var;
  cout << var << endl;
}
```

и выводит на печать `2`. То есть несмотря на то, что никаких мер по устранению неоднозначности мы не предприняли, MSVC смело полагает, что "победить" в этом случае должна `A::bar` из `B` (очевидно, *первой* по списку базы `D`). Таких правил в спецификации языка нет.

Comment: Способ сослаться на базовый тип получается как раз **неоднозначный**. Он был бы однозначным при виртуальном наследовании. Но как же в таком случае сослаться на нужные экземпляры `var` из `method`?

Comment: @AnT Мда, я как-то немного иначе это себе представлял... Ну что ж, утешает по крайней мере то, что разработчики VC++ полагали точно так же, как и я :) А по поводу `public A::var` не можете внести ясность?

Comment: @alexolut: Способ сослаться на тип - однозначен. В этой программе всего один тип `A`. Неоднозначность тут только в выборе конкретного базового подобъекта по имени типа `A`.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, наверное, так, как я предложил в **update** к вопросу? Но тут встает второй вопрос - почему при этом `A::var` должен быть `public`?

Comment: @Harry: Это свойство protected доступа. Классу `X` доступ к protected членам `X` разрешается только через объекты типа `X` или типа, унаследованного от `X`.

Comment: @AnT А что тут не так? Чем, например, это - http://ideone.com/6Ifwc8 - отличается от примера с множественным наследованием? Почему при наследовании не множественном все работает?

Comment: @Harry: Так тут неоднозначности никакой нет. `A` однозначно идентифицирует тип, `A` однозначно идентифицирует базовый подобъект, в результате `A::var` однозначно идентифицирует унаследованный член класса.

Comment: @AnT Я о `protected` - почему он работает при одинарном наследовании, и не работает при множественном?

Comment: @Harry, не работает он и при одинарном. Вы перепишите пример так, чтобы он был похож на Ваше обновление и увидите сами.

Comment: @ixSci Уже увидел. Тогда как? Только через какую-то опосредованность в виде public-функций?